# Is it really usefull for performance to pass values by reference in foreach in PHP 7

Tags: php, performance, loops, foreach, reference

Since PHP7.0, foreach loops have been modified and a new behavior has been set to make reference quicker than before (foreach $tab as &$val).

But I've read many times that passing by reference is actually sometimes slower than a the common loop (foreach $tab as $val)

Is it always quicker ? Always slower ? Does it depend on what we are doing in the foreach loop ? Since references in PHP are not references it's confusing... I'm a bit sick of reading different answers about this subject across the web and I cant figure out where the truth is.

Thank you for bringing some light here ;)

Source : https://blog.eduonix.com/web-programming-tutorials/learn-changes-foreach-statement-php-7/ 
Source : http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php
Source : http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php
...

Answer (score 4):

**Executive Summary:**  You are worrying about a performance problem that does not exist.

**Details**

PHP uses "COW" (Copy On Write).

**Normal passing (`$val`):**

- Scalar -- pass the value.  Writing to it changes only the local copy.
- Structure/array/etc -- pass pointer to it.  If the receiver (`foreach` loop or `function` body) wants to change any part of the structure, the structure is copied.  The cost is proportional to the size of the structure.

**Pass by reference (`&$val`):**

- Scalar -- pass a pointer to the scalar so that the innards can actually change it.
- Structure -- pass the pointer.  If the receiver writes to the structure, it simply (efficiently) goes through the pointer to get to the item in the structure.  No COW.

The **wisdom** in the design is that 99% of the time PHP "just works", *and* is efficient, and the user does not need to know that there are two passing techniques.  The tricky part is that you need to understand when to do the `&$val` thing.

PHP is ***different*** than virtually all other languages.

- ALGOL 60 -- Pass by value or "name" (sort of like anonymous functions in newish languages)
- FORTRAN -- Only pass by "reference" (pointer).  A drawback is that if you pass a literal, the receiver can change the value of the literal!  (OK, that was a 'bug' baked into old compilers.)
- C -- Only pass by value.  But you could say (with syntax) that you want the pointer to the thing and then dereference on the inside.
- Pascal -- Value or Reference, but not identical to anything above (I forget the details).

It seems there are almost as many ways to "pass arguments" as there are Languages.

**Back to the Question:**

- If you are passing a scalar, there may be a tiny performance penalty by having `&$val`, and going through the pointer.
- If you are passing a structure and don't need to write to it, there is probably zero difference.
- If you are passing a structure and *do* need to write to it, then you should have decided on how to pass it based on whether you want the change to be preserved, *not* on performance.

Answer (score 0):

The language designers are simply trying to handle the situation where the array elements are *big,* and to clarify directly in the source-code exactly what is to occur.  You can now *tell* PHP that the variable, `$val`, is to contain a reference to the array-element, which means that the big-value won't be duplicated and the memory garbage-collector won't have more work to do, *and the source-code clearly says so.* Subsequent programmers who read this statement will know exactly what PHP is going to do.

Of course, references are naturally more-efficient than copying values around in memory.